# Ошибка установки библиотеки ZigZag (No module named 'Cython')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

Хочу установить библиотеку 'ZigZag'.

Ввожу:`sudo pip3 install zigzag` , и получаю такую ошибку

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-8tncns9u/zigzag/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-8tncns9u/zigzag/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тебе нужно предварительно установить `cython` и `numpy`:

```
pip3 install cython numpy
```

затем повтори установку:

```
pip3 install zigzag
```

Потом можешь удалить `cython` (`pip3 uninstall -y cython`), он нужен только на время установки. Это не из-за твоей системы или конфигурации, просто у библиотеки `zigzag` скрипт `setup.py` кривой, неверно конфигурирует C extensions для компиляции.